# Change the Tooltip of DistributionChart

Tags: plotting, charts, tooltip

DistributionChart automatically puts a Tooltip on the elements of the chart, which shows the Min, 25%, Median, 75% and Max of the data. I would like to add the count of how many elements are in the set, to this.

Some data:

```
data = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], n], {n, {10, 100, 1000}}];

DistributionChart[data]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can post-process the output of `DistributionChart` to modify the content of tooltips:

```
Module[{i = 1}, DistributionChart[data] /. 
  Grid[x_, o__] :> Grid[Prepend[x, {Style["count", Bold], Length[data[[i++]]]}], o]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can wrap each data set with `Tooltip` using the second argument to specify tooltip content:

```
ClearAll[toolTip]
toolTip = Tooltip[#, Grid[Transpose[{Style[#, Bold] & /@ 
    {"count", "max", "75%", "median", "25%", "min"}, 
  {Item[Length@#, Alignment -> Center], ##&@@Reverse @ Quantile[#, {0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1}]}}],
 Dividers -> GrayLevel[.3], Alignment -> {{Center, ".", {Left}}}, 
 Frame -> Black, BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1]]] &;

DistributionChart[toolTip /@ data]
```

[image]