# Adding metrics to the Tooltip of a BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: plotting, charts

Is it possible to display standard deviation and mean in addition to the currently displayed metrics in the Tooltip of a `BoxWhiskerChart`.

```
BoxWhiskerChart[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]]
```

[image]

Currently, it has 5 metrics (max, Q3, median, Q1 and min) and I want to add more metrics to the Tooltip. I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Have a look here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188276/change-the-tooltip-of-distributionchart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

label[data_, index_, label_] := Grid[
  Prepend[
   Transpose[
    {Style[#, Bold] & /@ {"max", "75%", "median", "25%", "min", 
       "μ", "σ"},
     #@data & /@ {Max, Quantile[#, 3/4] &, Median, Quantile[#, 1/4] &,
        Min, Mean, StandardDeviation}}],
   {StringForm["Case: ``", index[[2]]], SpanFromLeft}],
  Frame -> All]

SeedRandom[1234];

data = Table[
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ, 1], 
    100], {μ, {0, 3, 2, 5}}];

BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[label[##], Tooltip] &), 
 ChartLabels -> Range[Length[data]]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** The default definition for [`Quantile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantile.html) does not give the same results as [`Quartiles`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quartiles.html). From the documentation, "Quartiles[list] is equivalent to Quantile[list, {1/4, 1/2, 3/4}, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}]."

For example,

```
(Quantile[#, {1/4, 1/2, 3/4}] & /@ data) == (Quartiles /@ data)

(* False *)

(Quantile[#, 1/2] & /@ data) == (Median /@ data)

(* False *)

(Quantile[#, {1/4, 1/2, 3/4}, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}] & /@ data) === 
    (Quartiles /@ data)

(* True *)

(Quantile[#, 1/2, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}] & /@ data) == 
    (Median /@ data)

(* True *)
```

Using the modified `Quantile`

```
label2[data_, index_, label_] := 
 Grid[Prepend[
   Transpose[{Style[#, Bold] & /@ {"max", "75%", "median", "25%", "min", 
       "μ", "σ"}, #@data & /@ {Max, 
       Quantile[#, 3/4, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}] &, Median, 
       Quantile[#, 1/4, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}] &, Min, Mean, 
       StandardDeviation}}], {StringForm["Case: ``", index[[2]]], 
    SpanFromLeft}], Frame -> All]

BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[label2[##], Tooltip] &), 
 ChartLabels -> Range[Length[data]]]
```

(* same chart with modified tooltips *)

Comment: This is awesome, Thanks @Bob